# problems with python lists and columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, multiple-columns

Hello I have the following code, where in the "filter" part, I filter a program by channel and year, and with group by I make the average per day of the column where the rating comes from.

```
año=[2019,2020]
base2= dataframe
channels=[lista con canales]

def ran_diario(base2,año,channels):

lista=[]
df = pd.DataFrame()

for h in año:
    for i in range(1,53):
        filtro=base2[base2.Year.isin([h]) & base2.Channel.isin(channels) & base2.Week.isin([i])]  
        filtro = filtro[filtro['Description'].str.contains('[a-z]*|[a-z]*'.join(word),case=False)]
        filtro["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(filtro["Date"])      
        a=filtro.groupby("Date", as_index=False)[targets].mean()
        lista.append(a)
        df["Year"]=h
        df["Week"]=i
        df=df.append(lista,ignore_index=True)
    
return (df)
```

the output I get is:

```
      Year  Week      Date              rat %
0   2020.0  52.0 2018-12-31            0.000000
1   2020.0  52.0 2019-01-01            0.000000
2   2020.0  52.0 2019-01-02            0.000000
3   2020.0  52.0 2019-01-03            0.000000
4   2020.0  52.0 2019-01-04            0.130000
..     ...   ...        ...                 ...
1      NaN   NaN 2020-01-12            0.000000
0      NaN   NaN 2020-02-01            0.066667
0      NaN   NaN 2020-02-08            0.000000
0      NaN   NaN 2020-02-15            0.035000
0      NaN   NaN 2020-02-29            0.000000
```

As you can see, the date and rat% column are fine but the year column puts me at the beginning of the year 2020 when it is 2019 and in the week that goes according to the i of the for it only puts the last one which is 52 and in the data of " date "for 2020 fill them with NaN The output should be:

```
     Year  Week       Date           rat %
0   2019.0   1.0 2018-12-31            0.000000
1   2019.0   2.0 2019-01-01            0.000000
2   2019.0   3.0 2019-01-02            0.000000
3   2019.0   4.0 2019-01-03            0.000000
4   2019.0   5.0 2019-01-04            0.130000
..     ...   ...        ...                 ...
1   2020.0   1.0 2020-01-12            0.000000
0   2020.0   2.0 2020-02-01            0.066667
0   2020.0   3.0 2020-02-08            0.000000
0   2020.0   4.0 2020-02-15            0.035000
0   2020.0   5.0 2020-02-29            0.000000
```

Comment: the line `df["Year"]=h` and the next, being inside the loop, reset the value of the full column on each iteration...

Comment: read the [user guide for groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html)... both loops inside your function can be avoided with a full df filter and a groupby

Comment: thanks RichieV, if i solved the problem